# Eclipse cannot resolve jdt

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to build a project I work on which I already installed in some other computers, but I fail to install it on one of my computers. I installed the required eclipse addons, such as for eclipse.jdt libraries, but yet it does not resolve them, and I get this message whentrying to build:

[image]

The marked error -

> The import org.eclipse.jdt.core cannot be resolved

I tried to reinstall eclipse's and java's last versions and still I get errors.
How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Installing them lets you *use* the tools. How are you adding them to the Java Build Path?

Comment: I tried to add all the jars in eclipse/plugins folder to the project's build path but then I get lots of errors of the kind "Bundle 'org.eclipse.jdt.core' cannot be resolved"

Comment: Eclipse Plug-ins expect to run as part of an Eclipse Application. Are you saying that the unresolved import is not the problem you're having?